# Evaluate equations in pandas Series per row based in other series

Tags: python, pandas

I have several pandas Series like this:

```py
2025     A + B   
2026     
2027     A + B - C
2028     
2029
2030     101.2
```

Each serie has its own equations. I also have a dictionary with values. Values are also series with the same index (from 2025 to 2050), and contain several values, not only those necessary to evaluate the equations.

```py
values = {"A": pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]), "B": pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), "C": pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]), "D": pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 4, 0]), ..., }
```

I need to evaluate the series of equations per row first doing a ffill and then evaluating per row. Like this:
Process:

```py
Index  Equation     Result
2025   A + B        10 + 1   
2026   A + B        20 + 2
2027   A + B - C    30 + 3 - 3.3
2028   A + B - C    40 + 4 - 4.4
2029   A + B - C    50 + 5 - 5.5
2030   101.2        101.2
```

Speed matters here, because there are more than 200 series. The output will also be a Pandas series with index and Result, as follows:

```py
Index  Result
2025   11   
2026   22
2027   27.9
2028   39.6
2029   49.5
2030   101.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a dataframe out of your equations and values, you can convert the equation into something that references row values and `eval` it for each row:

```py
eqns = pd.Series(['A + B', None, 'A + B - C', None, None, '101.2'], index=range(2025, 2031))
values = {"A": pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]), "B": pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), "C": pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]), "D": pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 4, 0])}

df = pd.concat([eqns.reset_index(name='Equation').ffill(), pd.DataFrame(values)], axis=1)
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda r:eval(re.sub(r'([A-Z]+)', r"r['\1']", r['Equation'])), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   index   Equation     A    B    C    D  Result
0   2025      A + B  10.0  1.0  1.1  1.0    11.0
1   2026      A + B  20.0  2.0  2.2  3.0    22.0
2   2027  A + B - C  30.0  3.0  3.3  2.0    29.7
3   2028  A + B - C  40.0  4.0  4.4  4.0    39.6
4   2029  A + B - C  50.0  5.0  5.5  0.0    49.5
5   2030      101.2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   101.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#Values are also series with the same index (from 2025 to 2050), 
#in sample data not, so added indices

values = {k: pd.Series(list(v), index=s.index[:len(v)]) for k, v in values.items()}
print (values)
{'A': 2025    10
2026    20
2027    30
2028    40
2029    50
dtype: int64, 'B': 2025    1
2026    2
2027    3
2028    4
2029    5
dtype: int64, 'C': 2025    1.1
2026    2.2
2027    3.3
2028    4.4
2029    5.5
dtype: float64, 'D': 2025    1
2026    3
2027    2
2028    4
2029    0
dtype: int64}
```

Then convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and add columns from `dict`:

```
s = pd.Series(['A + B',None,'A + B - C',None,None,101.2],
              index=range(2025, 2031))


df = s.to_frame('Equation').join(pd.DataFrame(values))
```

For improve performance create groups by same formulas and use [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), reason for `try-except` is numeric values in `Equation`:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        x['Equation'] = x.eval(x.name) 
    except ValueError:
        x['Equation'] = x.name
        
    return x
    
out = (df.assign(Equation = df['Equation'].ffill())
         .groupby('Equation', group_keys=False)
         .apply(f))

print (out[['Equation']])
      Equation
2025      11.0
2026      22.0
2027      29.7
2028      39.6
2029      49.5
2030     101.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas..html):

```
# ffill the Equations (assuming empty cells are NaN)
df['Equation'] = df['Equation'].ffill()

# identify non-numeric rows
m = pd.to_numeric(df['Equation'], errors='coerce').isna()

# create DataFrame from values
# note that the index must match the other DataFrame
vals = pd.DataFrame(values)

# evaluate the formula per group of equation
df['Result'] = (df[m]
 .groupby('Equation', sort=False, group_keys=False)['Equation']
 .apply(lambda g: vals.loc[g.index].eval(g.name))
 .combine_first(df['Equation'])
)
```

Output:

```
   Index   Equation Result
0   2025      A + B   11.0
1   2026      A + B   22.0
2   2027  A + B - C   29.7
3   2028  A + B - C   39.6
4   2029  A + B - C   49.5
5   2030      101.2  101.2
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030],
                   'Equation': ['A + B', None, 'A + B - C', None, None, '101.2']})

values = {'A': pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]),
          'B': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
          'C': pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]),
          'D': pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 4, 0])}
```

##### series as input

If your input is a Series, then just make sure to convert it to DataFrame first (with the years are index if the Series in `values` also have years as indexes):

```
ser = pd.Series(['A + B', None, 'A + B - C', None, None, '101.2'],
                index=[2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030])

idx = [2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029]
values = {"A": pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], index=idx),
          "B": pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index=idx),
          "C": pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5], index=idx),
          "D": pd.Series([1, 3, 2, 4, 0], index=idx),
         }

df = ser.to_frame(name='Equation')

# the rest of the code is identical
df['Equation'] = df['Equation'].ffill()

m = pd.to_numeric(df['Equation'], errors='coerce').isna()

vals = pd.DataFrame(values)

df['Result'] = (df[m]
 .groupby('Equation', sort=False, group_keys=False)['Equation']
 .apply(lambda g: vals.loc[g.index].eval(g.name))
 .combine_first(df['Equation'])
)
```

Output:

```
       Equation Result
2025      A + B   11.0
2026      A + B   22.0
2027  A + B - C   29.7
2028  A + B - C   39.6
2029  A + B - C   49.5
2030      101.2  101.2
```